# 'NoneType' object is not iterable: What to do?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, web-crawler, nonetype

I try to build a webcrawler but unfortunately I do not know how to handle with the following error message? Does anyone have a solution in mind? "Call" contains the source code of the page I want to scrape and it is not "none" but when I do `print(test)` I receive "none". Actually, I am not completely sure if

```
test = call.find('p',class_ = re.compile('p p*'))
```

is correct. Any thoughts?

```
#Testing if URL contains necessary elements
            test_list = []
            test = call.find_all('p',class_ = re.compile('p p*'))
            for c in test:
                x = c.text.strip()
                test_list.append(x)
if ('Operator' in test_list) and ('Conference Call Participants' in test_list):
                #Basic Company Info Section
                #Create cc_id
                cc_id = counter
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-c44d70d4fe49> in <module>
      1 #Pull page details
----> 2 pullpagedetails(take1)

<ipython-input-50-afd0a6c99d59> in pullpagedetails(Url_list)
     45             test_list = []
     46             test = call.find('p',class_ = re.compile('p p*'))
---> 47             for c in test:
     48                 x = c.text.strip()
     49                 print(x)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: If you are getting ```print(test)``` as ```None```. You need to check this statement thorougly - ```test = call.find('p',class_ = re.compile('p p*'))```

Comment: What is  the class of the paragraph that you are trying to fetch using re.compile('p p*')?  Also you can just print the call and see whether it contains the source code of the page.

Comment: You could put in an extra line where you replace `test` by an empty array if it's None. For example (just above `for c in test:`: `test = [] if test is None else test`.